# ADB cannot find THL T9 Pro

Tags: adb, linux

I intalled Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32 on Ubuntu 16.04. I connected THL T9 Pro with USB debugging enabled. `adb devices` doesn't show any connected devices.

I used this command to install it: `sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot`

I would like to use it with WLD Unlock Chrome plugin.

Comment: As pointed out in the comments of other question try setting `udev ` rules as explained https://android.stackexchange.com/q/144966/131553

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get my device detected by ADB on Linux?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144966/how-do-i-get-my-device-detected-by-adb-on-linux)