# ADB: Phone is not recognised but Ubuntu 18.04 recognises it

Tags: adb, data-recovery, linux, data-transfer, lg-g3

My LG G3 phone (phone is rooted; OS is [Android Fulmics](https://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/development/rom-fulmics-rom-3-0-tweaks-hub-ota-v30b-t3304556)) is recognised by my laptop when I plug it in. The laptop is running Ubuntu 18.04 and I can easily copy data from and to my phone.

I have recently installed the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) (`sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb`). Then, I wanted to reach my device and typed `adb devices`.

When functioning properly, [it **should** return something like this](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/adb/):

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 
5200d6fd904b2200    device
```

But when I tried it, it returned this:

```
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

So, `List of devices attached` appeared **first** and no device was listed.

When I type `adb devices` again, I get this:

```
List of devices attached
```

I have also tried to use `sudo adb devices` instead of `adb devices` but the results were the same.

When the ADB would work, I would try to use it for data recovery purposes as [described here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/200469/271628). Maybe the `pull` command can do what I want.

Comment: Have you checked with the solutions on [How do I get my device detected by ADB on Linux?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/144966/16575) and [ADB on Ubuntu does not recognize Nexus 4](/q/53554/16575)? Pointer: UDev rules, `adb.ini`.

Comment: [Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBsGp.png) “Entwickleroptionen” = “Developer options”, “USB-Debugging-Autorisierungen widerrufen” = “Revoke USB debugging authorisations”, “Debugging-App festlegen: Keine Debugging-App festgelegt” = “Set debugging app: No debugging app set”, “Auf Debugger warten” = “Waiting for debugger”.

Comment: According to the screenshot, USB debugging is turned off. Without that turned on, ADB cannot see the device.

Comment: But how can I turn it on? It seems to be impossible.

Comment: Does the toggle not work? Then I'd recommend making that the question (ask a new one along the lines of "cannot turn on USB debugging"). Sounds like a bug to me, though, if that toggle is really grayed out / deactivated.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14251564/8713892) has helped me a lot. I hope I can figure out the rest now.

Comment: Oy… Sure one has to activate USB debugging *before* plugging the cable in. That was too obvious for me to think it might be the issue. Glad your problem solved that easy – and thanks for self-answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14251564/8713892) has solved my problem. I could not turn on USB debugging because the phone was connected to my computer. You have to unplug the phone first, start the USB debugging and plug it back in. Then, `adb devices` worked.

Answer (score 0):

For one plus 6 I had to switch off developer mode

-> connect USB  to phone

-> switch on developer mode

-> switch on debugging mode

-> a prompt appears to allow pc to connect

-> select yes