# TWRP tells me: adb: sideload connection failed: insufficient permissions for device: user in plugdev group; are your udev rules wrong?

Tags: twrp, side-loading, oneplus-7-pro

```
❯ adb sideload lineage-17.1-20201108-nightly-guacamole-signed.zip
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
adb: sideload connection failed: insufficient permissions for device: user in plugdev group; are your udev rules wrong?
See [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] for more information
adb: trying pre-KitKat sideload method...
adb: pre-KitKat sideload connection failed: insufficient permissions for device: user in plugdev group; are your udev rules wrong?
See [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] for more information
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because TWRP doesn't support sideloading on the One Plus 7 Pro. From [the official port page](https://twrp.me/oneplus/oneplus7pro.html)

> If you don't download the zip file to your device first for any reason, **you will need to adb push the zip to the device because MTP is not currently working on the OnePlus 7 Pro in TWRP.** If you are unable to use adb, you can also use a USB stick with an OTG cable, if you have those handy.

Comment: `udev` permissions problem is a generic one arising due to unknown USB VID/PID: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/144966/218526. It doesn't always indicate that sideloading isn't supported. That's a device-specific case.