# How to disable MTP mode in an Android phone with a broken screen (USB debugging enabled)

Tags: usb, broken-screen, mtp

The screen of my phone broke some months ago, but luckily I had already enabled USB debugging and I trusted my PC, so I could use the phone with a USB with Vysor (a free open-source app) and I've been using it like that for months.

I was casually using the phone and I just changed it to MTP mode (I clicked the just once button so I could use the phone again, it's not the first time I do it and it went back to normal before) but now every single time I plug it in, it goes straight to MTP instead of charge only as it should be.

I tried resetting the phone by taking the battery off and putting it in again, no success.

Things that may be useful to know:

- The volume button doesn't work at all
- It's an LG K10 M250 without root, Android 7
- I tried 3 different USBs and it's the same story
- It's hopeless to touch the screen, saying it again just in case
- ADB Drivers are installed, Dr.Fone and EaseUS recovery apps tell me that debug is disabled even though I know that it's enabled.
- I won't fix the screen of this phone, the fix's worth another phone, which would be silly.

I googled a bunch and the results only show people with debugging disabled and/or MTP disabled, I have the exact opposite case, and I do need the phone to use banking apps and things like that, I would appreciate it if people want to suggest stuff I could do, my brain thinks that there should be a trick since the phone is connected after all.

I found the drivers on the device manager, it straight up says that it isn't connected. I disabled MTP Automount on Linux `udev` configuration and now a pop-up says "Unable to open MTP device "001,009""

[image: Vysor screenshot]

[image: ADB driver]

[image: Linux terminal lsusb]

Comment: Default USB mode can be set on a lot of devices in devoper menu.

Comment: @Robert "broken screen" and, according to the description, device not detected by ADB – so how to reach the developer menu?

Comment: @Izzy as mentioned in the question Vysor allows UI access. MTP and adb access can be active at the same time so this should still be possible.

Comment: well, that's the problem, i cant access to my phone UI with vysor to disable mtp, and adb access seems to not work with MTP on, i'll try my luck installing a custom adb driver with a modified .inf that allows both to be active at the same time

Comment: update, i'm trying to use vysor on linux but it doesn't find the device and it still straight up goes to MTP, tho i may be able to do stuff in linux that i cant on windows, but idk what those things are

Comment: @Robert the question also said that ADB cannot find the device ;) // ReddaZ: Check if `lsusb` sees the device (i.e. the USB connection is working). If that's the case, next check wether `adb` can see it with root powers (`sudo adb devices`). Further hints are in my answer on [How do I get my device detected by ADB on Linux?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144966/16575)

Comment: If adb does not work when MTP is active then the drivers are incorrectly installed. The phone should show up as three devices, one adb composite device, MTP device and ADB interface device. Change device manager to devices by connection view and check that. If it is not the case delete the existing entry and reconnect the phone.

Comment: @Izzy i did that whole guide, even the adb_usb.ini and still when i do sudo adb devices it says "List of devices attached" and nothing below, moreover, if i do sudo adb usb it says "error: no devices/emulators found", lsusb still shows my phone but it's the same as the attached screenshot

Comment: I tested ADB permissions on a secondary phone i have, which is a samsung grand prime, i was able to find it with ADB and use vysor in it, i also tested scrpy. My dad does have at home another phone of the same exact model as mine (m250ar), is it possible to do any shenanigans with it? and also, if i got a very lame usb that doesn't support MTP would it do the trick?

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas – apart from the usual "try a different cable, a different USB port, a different computer" (a different phone you already tried, so it's not the computer per-se).

Comment: yeah the LG k10 is a very silly phone tbh, i do remember the phone not being able to use mtp at all in windows 7, but it was able to use thetering, and i do have another pc with that, but it's unplugged and stuff, i'll try that someday

Comment: each mode has it's own device id, so adb was enabled for charge mode but not for mtp mode (otherwise adb would work on linux). charge mode is maybe active during start-up, poll adb devices and figure out

Comment: nothing ever shows up on adb devices and i followed a couple of guides to make it appear (using vendor id and that stuff), i do have another device and debug works well and apps that use it do aswell, so i really dont know the problem, the device shows up in find my phone with google, maybe i can remotely install an app with google play but whether or not will i be able to use it is another story too, so i kinda gave up